# What does "as_" in django query means?

Tags: python, django, model

I am wondering what "as_" in django query means. I have 1 query: User.objects.filter(username = "some_username").as_manager.something but in User model there is no "as_manager". Then in some other model called "Manager" I got "something" which is exactly what is returned. Is it some kind of deep django knowledge that "as_" can guide me to other model? Or is it "as_manager" somewhere which I cannot spotted.
I only add that User model extends from django AbstractUser.

Comment: `as_manager` is not magic, it's just a method on QuerySet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair question. I've wondered myself. But, looking through the source code, it only seems to prepend any particular methods/functions that present the object in certain formats or already defined objects like say:

- as_sql
- as_view
- as_table
- as_p
- etc...

I don't think it means anything as far as a "magical" construct or dynamic function name.